# Test the structure of a XML string

Tags: php, xml, symfony, phpunit

I need to test a function which creates a SimpleXMLElement and converts it to a string with asXML().
For that, I want to check the structure of the file to verify if there is inside "" etc. and 1 to 10 times a particular structure with ''.

I wanted to use assertEqualXMLStructure() but it's deprecated... so I could create an expected XML structure and use assertXmlStringEqualsXmlFile() but that wouldn't check the structure but all the XML content (and it's not each time the same).

Would you know a method to do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recreated assertEqualXMLStructure into a Trait and I customized it to drop the children count checking.
There is maybe a simpler way but it seems to work... !